# Simple Harmonic Motion $\omega$'s sign concern

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics, radicals

I tried to prove that $x(t)=A \sin(\omega t + \phi)$ knowing that $$\frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2}=-\omega^2 x$$ and $x=A$ when $v=0$, where $v = \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}$.

Since $\frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2} = v\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}$ I got the equation $$v \frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}=-\omega^2 x \Rightarrow v\text{d} v = -\omega^2 x\text{d} x \Rightarrow v^2=\omega^2(A^2-x^2)$$

This is the point where I get confused. Taking square root gives

> $$(1)\quad v=\pm \omega\sqrt{A^2-x^2} \Rightarrow \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = \pm \omega \sqrt{A^2-x^2} $$

and the $\pm$ sign is annoying. Even though $\sqrt{A^2-x^2}$ is zero for some $t$s, I tried to write

> $$(2) \quad \frac{dx}{\sqrt{A^2-x^2}}=\pm\omega dt \Rightarrow \arcsin\frac{x}{A}=\pm \omega t+ \phi \Rightarrow x(t) = A\sin(\pm \omega t +\phi)$$

Those are my two concerns: the $\pm$ sign in the final equation and the possible division by $0$ in $(2).$

How could I fix this?

Comment: The differential equation at the top should be $\ddot x = -\omega^2 x$.

Comment: There isn't really anything to fix. The $\pm$ is absorbed by both $\phi$ and $A$ once you use the odd property of sine. The possible division by $0$ isn't possible to "fix" either, as they say, it is a feature, not a bug. If we have the initial conditions $x(0) = A$, $x'(0) = 0$, notice that we'd have two solutions, $x(t) = A$ and $x(t) = A\sin(\omega t + \frac{\pi}{2})$, so we lose uniqueness. It's the not the division by $0$ that brought this on, but the fact that $\sqrt{A^2-x^2}$ had an unbounded derivative as a function of $x$.